# Push Notification using flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter

> I want to ask about the best way for push notification by using flutter and node.js API I used some of libraries but this libraries when I forced turn off app the notification does not receive and sometimes even app work the notification does not receive directly and I do not use firebase so I want the best ways to make the notification received directly when I push notifications even the app is closed or forced closed and it will be good if you have tutorial about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Signal is good for push notification within your needs. Here's some links:
Flutter setup: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup 
API documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-api

Answer (score 0):

You follow this.This is using `Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

Setup Link : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/